# How can I include Twitter Bootstrap in my php application?

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I'm using MAMP as my server and I've downloaded the bootstrap documentation and included them in my htdoc folder where all my files go to. I've also linked them using the `<script>` tag but bootstrap doesn't seem to be working. I just get normal html styling here. How can I fix this, and what can I do to let bootstrap working in my app? Thanks!

Comment: are you using a cdn? are you routing correctly ?

Comment: what's cdn? i'm using the mamp program the css and js files are in the same folders as the php files i'm using for my app

Comment: -1 : `what's cdn??` and `<script type="<bootstrap>" src="bootstrap"></script> insteadd`, you dont know how to include basic javascript file and expect spoon feeding here????...consider doing some homework before posting a questions please!!

Comment: dood i know <bootstrap> just mentioned bootstrap. i know it's supposed to be <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

Comment: @user3027052 : `<?php echo '<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>'; ?>` for JS files and `<?php echo '<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">'; ?>` for CSS files...thats the difference between `script` and `link` and its the method to include using php.....and its dude btw, not dood!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the stylesheet in order for twitter bootstrap to work.

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Withouth more details it's really hard to know what's not loading for you.
If you open the site with google chrome, and look on the network tab, does it show that the .css file loads for you ?

Comment: i did <script type="<bootstrap>" src="bootstrap"></script> insteadd. What's the difference between link href and that? New to php here. transitioning from ror.